# Mock a function from another file - Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am writing Unit test cases for my application. There is one function which is written in Utils section and Used in all files. I wanted to mock this Utils function whenever I need but I am unable to do so.

Here is my code setup:

Utils.js

```
> const getData = (name) => "Hello !!! " + name;
> 
> const getContact = ()=> return Contacts.mobile;
> 
> export {
>     getData,
>     getContact }
```

Login.js (Which uses Utils.js)

```
    const welcomeMessage = (name) => {

    return getData(name);
    }
```

My Test file (Login.spec.js)

```
import { getData } from '../../src/utils';


jest.mock('getData', () => jest.fn())


describe('User actions', () => {

    it('should get username', () => {
        const value = 'Hello !!! Jest';
        expect(welcomeMessage('Jest')).toEqual(value);
    });

});
```

When I run my test case then I am getting this error:

```
 Cannot find module 'getData' from 'Login.spec.js'
```

I tried to find the solution on official Jest Documentation and on SO as well but couldn't found anything. I am unable to fix this error and mock this function.

Answer (score 41):

The first argument of `jest.mock(...)` must be a module path:

```
jest.mock('../../src/utils');
```

because the `utils` module is your code, not a 3rd lib, so you must learn manual mock of jest:
https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/manual-mocks.html

if you had this file: `src/utils.js`

you can mock it by creating a file: `src/__mocks__/utils.js`

content of this file is the replication of the original but replace the implementation by `getData = jest.fn()`

on you test file, just call: `jest.mock('../../src/utils');` at begin of file.

then when you're familiar with, you can call that function inside `beforeEach()` and call its counter `jest.unmock('../../src/utils');` insider `afterEach()`

An easy way to think about it is that:

when you call `jest.mock('../../src/utils');`, it means you tell `jest` that:

> hey if the running test meets the line `require('../../src/utils')`, don't load it, let load `../../src/__mocks__/utils`.

Comment: in that case how does jest know that I have to mock getData as it is not a module it is just a function.

Comment: if you implement manual mock, jest only load your mocked module which only contains your mocked implementations of all your functions

Comment: is it possible for you to show me an example as I am new to Jest and it seems little bit confusing to me. @Khoa

Comment: @Khoa What if I want to mock a function in the same file Im testing?

Comment: @David: I must say I cannot answer your question. It's because I need a context. This means you must provide me a specific example like the author of this question. Unittest cannot be applied for any code. That's why people said, "write testable code".

Answer (score 33):

I got the same question and finally I find the solution.  I post it here for the one who got the same issue.

Jest test file:

```
import * as utils from "./demo/utils";
import { welcomeMessage } from "./demo/login";

// option 1: mocked value
const mockGetData = jest.spyOn(utils, "getData").mockReturnValue("hello");

// option 2: mocked function
const mockGetData = jest.spyOn(utils, "getData").mockImplementation((name) => "Hello !!! " + name);

describe("User actions", () => {
    it("should get username", () => {
        const value = "Hello !!! Jest";
        expect(welcomeMessage("Jest")).toEqual(value);
    });
});
```

references:
https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestfnimplementation

[`jest.spyOn(object, methodName)`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname)

> Creates a mock function similar to jest.fn but also tracks calls to
> object[methodName]. Returns a Jest mock function.

Note: By default, jest.spyOn also calls the spied method. This is different behavior from most other test libraries. If you want to override the original function, you can use:

```
jest.spyOn(object, methodName).mockImplementation(() => customImplementation)
```

or

```
object[methodName] = jest.fn(() => customImplementation);
```

Comment: Using `jest.spyOn` in top-level scope like in your example makes tests fail. Wrapping it in `beforeEach` solves the issue. I have no idea why this happens.

Answer (score 20):

### Using `jest.spyOn` fails in 2022

I was trying to recreate [sherwin waters solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66669162/3978701) using `jest.spyOn` but it was not working. Don't know why.

> **UPDATE**: Now I know why. I was using Create-React-App and with new version they changed default flag `resetMocks` is now set to true by default [source](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9935). That's why we need to declare them in `beforeEach` as they are cleaned after each test.

```js
// ./demo/welcomeMessage.js
import { getData } from "./utils"

export const WelcomeMessage = ({name}) => {
    return getData(name)
}

// ./demo/utils.js
const getData = (name) => `Hello ${name}!`;

export { getData }

// ./App.js
import { WelcomeMessage } from "./demo/welcomeMessage";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>My app</h1>
      <p>
        <WelcomeMessage name={'John'} />
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

// ./App.test.js
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';
import * as utils from "./demo/utils";

jest.spyOn(utils, "getData").mockReturnValue("mocked message");  // this doesn't work as intended

describe('App', () => {
  test('renders header', () => {
    render(<App />);
    expect(screen.getByText(/My app/i)).toBeInTheDocument()
  });

  test('renders correct welcome message', () => {
    render(<App />)
    expect(screen.getByText(/mocked message/i)).toBeInTheDocument()
  });
})
```

### Solution #1 using `jest.spyOn` in `beforeEach`

Wrap `jest.spyOn` in `beforeEach` block

```
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.spyOn(utils, "getData").mockReturnValue("mocked message");
});
```

Now tests should work correctly. This is similar to this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69163310/3978701).

### Solution #2 using `jest.mock`

Instead of using `import * as ...` we can mock our module with `jest.mock`. Following test works fine:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

jest.mock('./demo/utils', () => ({
    getData: () => 'mocked message'
}));

describe('App', () => {
  test('renders header', () => {
    render(<App />);
    expect(screen.getByText(/My app/i)).toBeInTheDocument()
  });

  test('renders correct welcome message', () => {
    render(<App />)
    expect(screen.getByText(/mocked message/i)).toBeInTheDocument()
  });
})
```

This approach is harder to use if we want to have multiple mocked implementations, e.g. one for testing failing cases and one for normal cases. We would need to use `doMock` and async imports.

Comment: This is the correct answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

another solution would fake this by doing something like:

```
window['getData'] = jest.fn();
```

Comment: This can lead to issues that are difficult to debug