# global Jest SpyOn function doesen't call the original function

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, jestjs

I hope someone might help me understanding the interactivity of js prototypes and `jest.spOn()`.

I have a small Example:
An example class in file `TestObj.ts`:

```js
export default class TestObj {
  foo() {
    // Do Something e.g.
    console.log("Hello World!");
  }
}
```

The following example Test Case is succeeding but the `console.log` is never executed.

```js
import TestObj from './TestObj';

const spyObj = jest.spyOn(TestObj.prototype, 'foo');
test('debug test', () => {
  const obj = new TestObj();
  obj.foo();
  expect(spyObj).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

If I change the Example Test Case to the following, the test succeeds and the `console.log` statement is called as expected.

```js
import TestObj from './TestObj';

test('debug test', () => {
  const spyObj = jest.spyOn(TestObj.prototype, 'foo');
  const obj = new TestObj();
  obj.foo();
  expect(spyObj).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Any idea why the version, using the global spyOn variable does not work as expected?

---

## Edit:

It seems to be not related to prototypes.
The same Issue is there for a function without any kind of class,
editing the First Code snippet (`TestObj.ts`) to this:

```js
export foo() {
  // Do Something e.g.
  console.log("Hello World!");
};
```

We receve the same issue for the updated second snipped. (The test succeeds but the console log is never reached.)

```js
import * as testlib from './TestObj';

const spyObj = jest.spyOn(testlib, 'foo');
test('debug test', () => {
  testlib.foo();
  expect(spyObj).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

However if we update the second snippet to the following the test succeeds and the console log is executed:

```js
import * as testlib from './TestObj';

const spyObj: jest.SpyInstance;

beforeEach(() => {
  spyObj = jest.spyOn(testlib, 'foo');
});
test('debug test', () => {
  testlib.foo();
  expect(spyObj).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

However I have still no clue why I discover this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

who ever comes across this post,

### Problem explanation

I did a lot more of research(try&error, mdn, jest manpage and a lot of medium articles) and I guess that I found out the reason for the strange behavior. To understand this issue it is important to know a number of points:

- 1: JS prototypes are global variables, every object of the corresponding type relies on.
- 2: Jest does not reset global variables after every test, changes made before, or inside any test to a global variable will be kept for the whole test suite (file).
- 3: The jest spy on function is actually a mockup of the specified function with an implementation calling the function it self. e.g.:
  `jest.SpyOn(TestObj.prototype, 'foo');` actually is implemented as: `TestObj.prototype.foo = new jest.fn().mockImplementation(()=>{original_TestObj.prototype.foo()});`
  This means spying on a function of a class prototype is actually changing a global variable.
- 4: Depending on your jest config, there is the possibility to reset mockup functions before every test to the default value. But be careful the default function for `spyOn` seems to be the same as for `jest.fn()` it self, an empty implementation, which means the mock-up is still callable but no code, especially not the original implementation is executed.

---

### Solution

- avoid changing global variables, if you want your testcases independent from each other.
- avoid spying on prototypes, in test cases, if you require the spy only in a single test try to spy on the local object eg:

```js
test('should foo', () => {
  const testObj = new TestObj();
  const spyOnFn = jest.spyOn(testObj, 'foo');

  // Do anything 

  expect(spyOnFn).to//Have been anything
});
```

- if requiring `spyOn` implementations of the same function
  in more than one test try to create a global variable for the Test
  but use the before each functionality of jest to setup the Spy. This
  functionality is executed after the reset of all mocks (if enabled).
  e.g.:

```js
let spyOnFunction1: jest.SpyInstance;

beforeEach(()=> {
  spyOnFunction1 = jest.spyOn(TestObj.prototype, 'foo');
});
```

Comment: I don't understand how it's related to the second example that is not related to prototypes. Could you elaborate why `spyObj = jest.spyOn(testlib, 'foo');` has to be inside `beforeEach`?

Comment: It is related to global variables rather than to prototypes. It does not matter if there is a global variable, which is part of a module object or it is part of a class instance (object) and related to a prototype. The beforeEach block is actually not really a solution but some kind of working hack. You still overwrite the global variable but you do this before each testcase with a fresh instance so it will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed explanation and solution :) Just to supplement Problem point #4, since I encountered the issue where the first call uses the actual implementation and then nothing after `jest.clearAllMocks()` and `jest.resetAllMocks()`, I tried adding `jest.restoreAllMocks()` and worked. Thanks!